# laravel after login NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel

I use `php artisan make:auth` and edit `route.php` like this.

```
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('/', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
Route::get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@Logout');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@reset');
Route::get('password/reset/{token?}', 'Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm');
Route::get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@register');
```

I think I just change route's URI, but after login It brings error like this :

NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

I edit `AuthController.php` `protected $redirectTo = '/';` to `protected $redirectTo = '/home';`

before route:list

[image]

Comment: Do you have `public function index()` in `HomeController` ?

Comment: @EddyTheDove yes, It has `return view('home');` and I have `home.php` view file too.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I change `Route::post('/', 'Auth\AuthController@login');` to `Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
`

Comment: So everything working fine now?